# java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table abc.company_vals: companyId, companyName

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, datastax

Using libs , spark-cassandra-connector_2-11.jar and spark-sql-2.4.1.jar

Have Cassandra table as below

```
CREATE TABLE abc.company_vals(
    companyId int,
    companyName text,
    year int,
    quarter text,
    revenue int,
    PRIMARY KEY (companyId, year)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( year DESC );
```

Trying to insert data into the above using spark-structured streaming as below

```
List<Row> data  = Arrays.asList(
                    RowFactory.create(10002 , "TCS",2004,"Q4",7800),
                    RowFactory.create(10003, "GE",2004,"Q4",7800),
                    RowFactory.create(10004, "Oracle",2004,"Q4",7800),
                    RowFactory.create(10005, "epam",2004,"Q4",7800),
                    RowFactory.create(10006, "Dhfl",2004,"Q4",7800),
                    RowFactory.create(10007, "Infosys",2004,"Q4",7800)
               )

StructType schema = new StructType()
                      .add("companyId", DataTypes.IntegerType)
                      .add("companyName", DataTypes.StringType)
                      .add("year", DataTypes.IntegerType)
                      .add("quarter", DataTypes.StringType)
                      .add("revenue", DataTypes.IntegerType);

             Dataset<Row> companyDf = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema).toDF();


             companyDf
             .write()
             .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .option("table","company_vals")
                .option("keyspace",  "abc")
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .save();
```

I changed the order of the table like pk , cluster key and rest of the columns, changed StructType & input accordingly...but still same error.

**Getting error :**

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table abc.company_vals: companyId, companyName
at com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns.selectFrom(ColumnSelector.scala:44)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:385)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation.insert(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
```

What am I doing wrong here ? how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Spark Connector is using case sensitive names, while in CQL they are case insensitive until the columns names are put into double quotes. So you either need to declare fields in the table as case-sensitive as `"companyId"` and `"companyName"` correspondingly, or use lowercased names in your Spark app.

Comment: thank you so much , I really owe a lot to you ...Just checked the table columns ..those are created in lower case... I dropped and created but no use same scenario ...now I changed the column names into lower case....thanks a billion